# Creating sheets into two different workbooks and naming them after the list in ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, addition

I have a file where names are listed in column A with information in the other columns. With an `IF` function I decide which workbook I need to use, then I add a sheet into the specific workbook containing the names in column A. The code works fine until row 7 then stops working and I have no idea why. I got `Run-time error 1004`. Once, it worked fine, and then I tested it again and it completely crashed.  Can you please help me with this?

```
    Dim Ki As range
    Dim ListSh As range
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lr As Integer
    Dim wbkRAM As Workbook
    Dim wbkPSS As Workbook

    Set wbkRAM = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\212478002\Desktop\VCP\PSS\RAM.xlsx")
    Set wbkPSS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\212478002\Desktop\VCP\PSS\PSS.xlsx")

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

                 Set ListSh = .range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

            End With

    For x = 1 To lr

        For Each Ki In ListSh

          x = x + 1

                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "B") = "PSS" Then

                        wbkPSS.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Ki.Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "D").Copy
                        wbkPSS.Sheets(Ki.Value).Cells(1, "A").PasteSpecial

                Else
                        wbkRAM.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Ki.Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "C").Copy
                        wbkRAM.Sheets(Ki.Value).Cells(1, "A").PasteSpecial
                End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I added it accidentally sorry,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, if you get an error, hit debug and let me know what line is causing the error..

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim lr As Integer
Dim wbkRAM As Workbook
Dim wbkPSS As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Sub dunnothename()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbkRAM = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\212478002\Desktop\VCP\PSS\RAM.xlsx")
    Set wbkPSS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\212478002\Desktop\VCP\PSS\PSS.xlsx")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ListSh = ws.Range("A2:A" & lr)
    For x = 1 To lr
        If ws.Cells(x, 2) = "PSS" Then
                wbkPSS.Sheets.Add(After:=wbkPSS.Sheets(wbkPSS.Sheets.Count)).Name = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
                ws.Cells(x, 4).Copy wbkPSS.Sheets(ws.Cells(x, 1).Value).Cells(1, 1)
        Else
                wbkRAM.Sheets.Add(After:=wbkRAM.Sheets(wbkRAM.Sheets.Count)).Name = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
                ws.Cells(x, 3).Copy wbkRAM.Sheets(ws.Cells(x, 1).Value).Cells(1, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well this did not really help. The code wont jump to the next row if i don't add this line. I think there must be something with the for each loop but i dont know what and the code sometimes run till the 7th row sometimes only the 2nd...I really dont understand it.

Comment: Oh you forget to define Ki. Thats the problem now.

Comment: yep, my bad, updated the answer..this will still fail if you try to add a sheet with a name that already exists, but you can add a check for that

Comment: It works fine! :) Thank you I am really grateful! I just added a code that defined Ki.